# Как сгруппировать классы для модели MVC

Tags: java, mvc

Программа на swing, которая предлагает пользователю загрузить n файлов excel и затем выдает итоговый отчет в виде одного excel файла.

я разбил классы по пакетам, хочу чтобы структура удовлетворяла mvc. у меня получилось так. прошу проверить.

```
package view 
[
    // отрисовка интерфейса. кнопка для указания
    // пути к файлам и кнопка запуска.

    Gui.java
    // отрисовка строки состояния.
    ToolBar.java
]
```

```
package model
[
    // пути для загрузки/выгрузки файлов и пр. константы;
    Constants.java

    // свои исключения;
    Exceptions.java

    // содержит метод, - файл "Totals" пишется в папке клиента;
    WriteFileTotal.java 
]
```

```
package controller
[
    // читаем все файлы. получается 10 сырых файлов;
    ReaderAllFiles.java

    // обрабатываем файлы. получается 10 обработанных файлов;
    Logic.java

    // формируется итоговый файл "Totals" и 
    // передаем в WriteFileTotal.java; 
    Totals.java 
]
```

Comment: на смену swing в Java 8 пришел JavaFX 8, при создании проекта автоматически будет создана структура, подумайте о переходе на новый фреймворк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла идею, то вся логика с обработкой классов должна оказаться в package model. В контроллере должен быть только контроль (т.е. передача запросов в модель).

```
Model -> read files, form a new file, save(?) the formed file
Controller -> gets file paths from view and sends them to model
View -> swing + show result
```

Comment: да что-то типа такого я хотел увидеть. спасибо.